# .child is not a functions

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am exercising to store data in firebase with the help of ReactJS. While following the documentation I built the following.

firebase.js

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";

const config = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: ""
  };

  class Firebase {
    constructor() {
      firebase.initializeApp(config);
    }
  }
   
  export default Firebase;
```

When I use the firebase config I get the error

> TypeError: *utils_firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3*_.default.child is not a function

This is how I have implemented it.

```
import React from 'react'
import ContactForm from "./ContactForm";
import Firebase from "../utils/firebase";


const Contacts = () => {

    const addOrEdit = obj => {
        Firebase.child('contacts').push(
            obj,
            err => {
                if(err) console.log(err);
            }
        );
    }
....
```

What is that I am missing here?

---

My solution.

It was a silly mistake in my `firebase.js` file, I never did `import "firebase/database";`

After adding that import and exporting, it solved and it's working now!

Comment: There's no `child` property defined in your firebase class, what did you expect?

Comment: @Phix I am trying to access `child` from firebase API itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking to access `child` in the Firebase Realtime Database API. But your `Firebase` does not expose that API in any way.

Why not simply **also** `import firebase from "firebase"` and then do:

```
firebase.database().reference('contacts').push(...)
```

?

---

Alternatively, you can expand your `Firebase` class to export the Firebase services you use:

```
  class Firebase {
    constructor() {
      firebase.initializeApp(config);
    }
    database() {
      return firebase.database();
    }
  }
```

And then call it as:

```
Firebase.database().reference('contacts').push(...)
```

Comment: I think I got confused over there for a minute, so I moved the config from firebase.js to the component itself, that did not work, but the alternative way also did not work. I am jumbled over this but thank you for the answer really appreciate it, maybe I can try and figure it out with this as a reference.

Comment: Another alternative I tried was `var fireDb = firebase.initializeApp(config);
   
export default fireDb.database();` but this also did not work

Comment: Please note that it's incredibly hard to help with "that did not work". Always include what **did** happen please (even if that is not what you wanted to happen), as it increases the chances we can help.

Comment: Hey @YashKaranke Did you get anywhere with this? If not, can you clarify what **did** happen in your code, and how that is different from what you expected. Stack Overflow is an incredibly inefficient interactive debugger, so we'll need you to talk us through what happens when you step through your code in a debugger.

Comment: Hey Frank, I am still working with the problem tried several different methods to fix this, I will surely update the question with more description, probably even add a codesandbox of this as well

Comment: Hey Frank, I've updated the question with where I made the mistake. thank you for your time :)